# how to set wide screen size in ISPF

Tags: display, zos, ispf

I am trying to get a wide screen in ISPF. I expect it is my ISPF settings since I am having the same problem with 2 different 3270 emulators.

If I want to get a 132 column wide screen, what is the setting that I should specify?
I tried setting terminal characteristics from option 0 to:

- Screen format: 3. Max
- Terminal Type 3. 3278

Should I be specifying a different terminal type?

I tried editing a file via option 2 that is 255 characters wide and I only see 0-72.

Can I get a screen wider than 132?

Comment: Is this an issue involving programming? [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from changing the `screensize` on the `Settings(0)` panel, you also need to change your emulator (pcomm or HOD) to refer to the wide size screen.

In PCOMM, it is the screensize parm; i.e., `Screensize=43x155` gives you 43 lines, each with 155 bytes long.

A similar setting is available for HOD. You need to make a change and then log back in to see the screen size change.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to go back to the emulator for that - figured just option 0 would suffice... 
For me, I'm using an open source tool called c3270 and it's a little more cryptic and restrictive, but I got 27x132 to work with:

c3270 -altscreen 27x132=\E[?40h\E[?3h -defscreen 27x132=\E[?40h\E[?3h

I didn't see much in the doc for c3270 on this so I'm not quite sure how to use the alternate and default screens, but this solves my immediate problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify default resources in the .c3270pro file in your home directory for c3270 [here in the wiki](https://x3270.miraheze.org/wiki/C3270).

You can set the [oversize resource](https://x3270.miraheze.org/wiki/Oversize_resource) to use a wider screen, for example:

```
c3270.oversize: 160x62
```

This should work with the default model, or you could add

```
c3270.model: 3279-4-E
```

Disclaimer: I have only tried this with x3270, but the doc suggests that it should work for c3270.

Comment: Thank you! That worked and that's way less clunky than the defscreen/altscreen I did.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to set the ISPF settings Screen format to 1 (Data). That way the screen is 80 columns wide for the most part and then wide when it is needed.

Comment: nice! thank you. That looks much cleaner. I never understood what those choices meant.

Comment: But remember if you do set the screen format to data (1) in the hope of having a wider screen, then you also must change your 3270 emulator to a Model 5 (27x132) or a custom size (i.e. 60x160) - just be sure your eyes can handle it :)